# Foliations with algebraic foliation chart

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

An algebraic foliation chart for a foliated manifold is a foliation chart for which the transition maps are polynomial maps.

> What is an example of an analytic  foliation of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ which does not admit an algebraic foliation chart?
>   In particular is there an algebraic foliation chart for foliation of the plane tangent to $cos y \partial_x +sin y \partial _y$